# why the Name mangling not happens?

Tags: c, gcc, name-mangling

```
extern int test();
int main()
{
    return test();
}
```

I build the code by `gcc -c -o test.o test.c`, and I find there is no name mangling when I run `nm test.o`. `nm` outputs `test` but not `_test`.

My environment is `ubuntu 16.04` `gcc 5.4.0`

Comment: While it is not really _name mangling_, adding an underscore to function names is something that depends on the tool chain you use. While developing for C16x microcontrollers, I used tools from Keil and Tasking. One did add an _, while the other did not. Even for the same CPU architecture. Therefore you need to read your tool chain documentation or your CPU's EABI description how calling conventions are for C functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be expecting global symbols to have an underscore prepended to them. This is something that isn't done in ELF which is the object format that linux uses. Older binary formats like a.out or coff required that, ELF doesn't.

Btw. the term "mangling" is usually used for C++ symbol mangling which is a different thing.

Answer (score 1):

Name mangling does not happen in C programs. It happens in C++ programs.

That's why you cannot overload functions in C but you can in C++.

Answer (score 1):

The `main` function returns after calling the function `test` The return value of `test` is then given to the return value of `main`.

No name mangling is required.